# URDF and Mesh for Pioneer 3AT

Tags: urdf, mesh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to model several Pioneer 3AT robots for a project, so I was hoping to find existing urdf and mesh files to use with gazebo. However, my search hasn't turned up anything and I'm not sure what to do next. Does anyone know where I can find what I'm looking for, or good places for me to look?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38570/urdf-and-mesh-for-pioneer-3at/) by [jerdman](https://answers.ros.org/users/2816/jerdman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2012-07-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [p2os_urdf](http://www.ros.org/wiki/p2os_urdf) package seems to contain urdf, meshes and Blender files for the Pioneer 3AT. You can directly grab them from svn:
https://usc-ros-pkg.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/usc-ros-pkg/trunk/p2os/p2os_urdf/
(Check out the 'defs','meshes' and 'models' directories)

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2